# Java Regular Expression for "mysql_free_result($myvar);" - Netbeans

Tags: java, regex, netbeans

I'm using netbeans and I'm working on a project in php. 
I need to use the find tool, looking for all the point in the project where the following string can appear

```
  mysql_free_result($myVarName);
```

$myVarName can be any name allowed in php.

Then I've to replace this string with

```
  mysql_free_result($myVarName); MyAdditionalString
```

To observe that $myVarName can be different for diffents points in the scripts, so the replace had to replace with correct var name.

Netbeans find tool can use a regular expression for search pattern, so what I've to write to find this points?

Comment: Is your question how you should write a regex in netbeans to refactor a variable name, that just happens to be in a PHP-file?

Comment: my question is about to write a regular expression that I can use in the search tool of netbeans.
This regular expression need to match "mysql_free_result($myVar)"
So I can use the search and replace function to append something after this instruction

Comment: That's more or less what I wrote. :) Anyway, you should remove the "PHP" tag since this question is all about regex and not PHP itself.

Comment: Yes, but instead of refactor is about to append :-)

Comment: neither is the topic about java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search with

```
         mysql_free_result\(\$[a-zA-Z]+\);
```

and replace with

```
        $0 myAdditionalString
```

Thanks to @Jakumi for the suggestion

Comment: if you add an `;` at the end, OP could replace with `$0 MyAdditionalString`. however, php vars can contain numbers and underscores as well ... see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqEditorBackReferences

Comment: Yes it's correct but in my case no numbers and underscores appears in a variable's name